# Read files in a loop [julia]?

Tags: file, makefile, julia, hdf5

I successfully store files in a loop. now l have 1000 files from 1 to 1000, l want to read them but it doesn't work.

```
for i in 1:1000
    h5open("path to file /file$i.h5", "w") do file
        write(file, "a", x)  # alternatively, say "@write file a"
    end
end
```

for writing it works well. but when it comes to read them it doesn't work.

```
for i in 1:1000
    h5open("  path to files/file$i.h5", "w") do file
        read(file, "a", x)  # alternatively, say "@write file a"
    end
end
```

how to fix that ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting an error you should write that in the question.

Also please look carefully at the docs first:

e.g. https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl
https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl/blob/master/doc/hdf5.md

and here

https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl/blob/master/doc/hdf5.md

To read from a file `read()` would take two arguments as in this example from the README page. Also the read object is assigned to a variable c.

```
c = h5open("mydata.h5", "r") do file
    read(file, "A")
end
```

To put this in a for loop and read each variable in you would be best constructing an array or other structure to put the values in first. And then assign and index of c to that variable e.g.

```
# initialise c to be 1000 elements X whatever you are reading in then ...
for i in 1:1000
    c[i] = h5open("mydataFilenumber$i.h5", "r") do file
        read(file, "A")
    end
end
```